# Breaking down tedious processes

Tags: content, wizard, user-generated-content

I wonder what are some good sample ways for breaking down tedious processes, e.g., creation of long content. Most sites present long forms - for example, eBay presents one long form for the details of a selling item. In contrast, I fairly like the way Airbnb breaks down the listing process into, first, a clean outline submission and then several tabs asking for details. I think this substantially reduces mental burden.

[image]
[image]

Does anyone know of any other sites out there that break down content creation well?

Ref: https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/new

Comment: What are you asking for specifically? Because this seems like an open ended question, as apposed to a straight forward, clear cut question that should lead to a definitive answer.

Comment: This seems like a perfectly clear cut question to me. Its also quite an important question as you don't want your users getting fed up with entering too much data and just giving up.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at these websites:

- www.roomorama.com
- www.wimdu.com
- www.9flats.com
- https://www.vayable.com/experiences-edit/new
- https://www.stay4free.com/step1

On many of these sites, you can simply sign up with Facebook and access the listing property page. In the last two links I think those have their sections broken down very well.

Answer (score 1):

Make as little of the content obligatory as possible before the form can be submitted.

Users should be able to return to it later and add extra info *if they want to*.